# Remove Express Session from Mongodb after destroy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I believe I followed the instructions to creating and connecting express-session to a store as shown below:

```
function getSessionStoreURL() {
    const env = app.get("env");
    if (env === "development") {
        return process.env.DEV_DB;
    }
    return process.env.PROD_DB;
}

app.use(
    session({
        secret: SESSIONS_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { secure: true },
        store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: getSessionStoreURL() })
    })
);
```

Here is the function that creates the session after login:

```
function createNewUserSession(req, userId, moreUserData) {
    try {
        const session = req.session;
        session.userId = userId;
        session.moreUserData = moreUserData;
        session.save();
        //...Some async code omitted for code brevity
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

Yet, when I explicitly call the following on **password change**, the session is destroyed somehow but when I checked my mongodb the session object is still there. So technically it was never destroyed in the store.

```
async destroySession(req) {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error destroying session:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Session destroyed');
        }
    });
}
```

Below are my packages:

```
"connect-mongo": "^5.0.0",
"express-session": "^1.17.3",
```

And please note that sessions are only created during login on my site. Not just by mere site visiting.

So, please what do I do to ensure once `req.session.destroy` is called, it should also immediately delete the session object from mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

`req.session.destory` will not tell the mongo store to destroy the session. you need to call `destroy` function of the `store` object.

```
async destroySession(req) {
    const sessionId = req.session.id;
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error destroying session:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Session destroyed');
            // destroy session in the store
            store.destroy(sessionId, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error destroying session in store:', err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Session destroyed in store');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank for your suggestion. I tried your code but the session is still on the db. When I logged sessionId to the console I noticed the sessionId does not even match any of the _id fields in my mongodb sessions collection. Do I need to store the sessionId explicitly to mongodb as well or something?

Comment: Also, is there no better way to do things. Because for every destroy from the store I need to open a connection to my database. That's alot, is there no way to use mongoose together with this instead?